# How to fatch a record from Power BI Dataset in Power Query M

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, dataset, powerquery

I am trying to fatch value from Power BI dataset from Power Query M.

I do not find any option yet to acccess PBI dataset from Power Query M code

Comment: Not possible to do it. If you could explain more of what you are trying to do, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

If the Dataset is on a Premium Capacity or a Premium Per User workspace, you can import data from the [XMLA endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-connect-tools).  EG

```
let 
  Endpoint = "powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/MyWorkspace",
  Query = "evaluate(MyTable)",
  Database = "MyDataset",
  Data = AnalysisServices.Database(Endpoint, Database, [Query=Query, Implementation="2.0"])
in 
  Data
```

Comment: I do not want to go via powerbi's API way. Can we have something written on Power Query M so that I can access other datasets

Comment: That’s M, not the REST API.